# Dialog box with textfield & combo box

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox, jdialog

I have a small question in one of the topics from Swing in Java.  I was trying to create a dialog box with:

1. label & a combo box (e.g.: gender:M/F) and
2. label & a text field (e.g.: what's your name:text field).

I want all the things in the same dialog-box.  Can anyone tell me how to approach the issue?

Comment: What did you tried? Show some efforts guy or no one will help.

Comment: Please have a look at [Customize JOptionPane Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12235299/1057230) and one more [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10309277/1057230) for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the component to a JPanel, then add the panel in the dialog.

Refer to this [tutorial](http://www.coderanch.com/t/338717/GUI/java/JOptionPane-custom-buttons-close-JOptionPane).

Comment: Please add a brief description and perhaps a snippet of the useful code from that site. If that site changes its content or is taken offline this answer loses all use. Thanks