# how to show items in JOptionPane.showOptionDialog horizontally?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, joptionpane

I'm trying to put a TextBox & a Button in a JOptionPane.showOptionDialog horizontally.
I've used this code.

```
JTextField txt = new JTextField();
JButton btn = new JButton("Button");
int value = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this,
                    new Object[]{txt, btn},
                    "Hello World",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                    null, null, null);
```

But TextBox & Button showing vertically.
How can I show them in horizontally ?
Please help...
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234850/customize-joptionpane-dialog) you can actually do it like this, setting an JPanel which has a textfield and a button.

```
int value = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this,
                    getPanel(),
                    "Hello World",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                    null, null, null);

private JPanel getPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextField txt = new JTextField(20);
    JButton btn = new JButton("Button");

    panel.add(txt);
    panel.add(btn);

    return panel;
}
```

**EDIT**
Each JPanel object is initialized to use a `FlowLayout`, unless you specify differently when creating the JPanel. as per the doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Comment: @JJPA It's working fine. I'm marking this as answered. Thanks a lot. One more question please: How to add items in jPanel vertically ? 
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
I'm using this, but not working.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TempExpt try with `new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)` as per the docit alligns components top to bottom I would make use of `new GridLayout(0,1)` instead. Try with that once. But the space will be divided equally.